# Angular6 wait ngOnInit in app.component to finish and then ngOnInit in child triggers

Tags: angular

In my project, I want to call a api during app.component initialize and the child component should wait till app.comonent to finish in ngOnInit()

in app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
// call getx()
     }
```

And in child.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(){
   // call gety()
  }
```

Execution order:
want gety() to wait till getx() to finish.

Comment: invoke child component when `getX `is finished use `<app-child *ngIf="flag"></app-child>` where the flag would be set iff getx is done executing

Comment: @Vikas, that's not what OP is asking for. He didnt say that he doesnt want the child component not to load at all until getX is resolved. Just that the getY doesnt get called.

Comment: Since this is a parent->child relationship, you can use an event emitter from the parent, and subscribe to it in the child. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @callback Perhaps you would want to go through the question again OP wants to load child component when `getX` is resolved `want gety() to wait till getx() to finish.` that's why I gave that solution

Comment: @callback Where did OP mention about  ` getY doesnt get called.`

Comment: @Vikas "want gety() to wait till getx() to finish.". Now that I read again, I think that OP mentions both scenarios... First, he talks about the child component not loading at all until getX Oninit of app component resolves.. then at the end he says "I just want getY to be called only when getX is resolved".. So I think we are both right and wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try with Promise something like:

in app.component.ts

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<bool> {

return new Promise<bool>(resolve,reject)=>{
  // call getx()
resolve(true); //or anything you want ot return maybe from getx()
});
}
```

in child.component.ts .. `extends` your app.component

```
async ngOnInit(): Promise<bool>{

   await super.NgOnInit();
 // call gety()
   resolve(true); //or anything you want ot return maybe from gety()
});
}
```

hope it helps you .. maybe you can archive it also with other ways (like do a emitter from your app.component.ts and listen it in your child component .. or other) .. hope it can help you!!!

Comment: By this way, say I have 100 child component then i need to do changes in all. Is there any other way to do without modifying child component.

Answer (score 0):

In your app component you can have a property:

```
wasGetXExecuted = false;
```

which you set to true after getX() function was executed.

In your child component you can create an input, like:

```
@Input() wasGetXExecuted: boolean;
```

Then in child component you can implement ngOnChanges lifecycle hook like:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['wasGetXExecuted'] != null) {
        if (changes['wasGetXExecuted'].previousValue === false &&
            changes['wasGetXExecuted'].currentValue === true) {
            this.getY();
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to bind input in app component template:

```
<child-component [wasGetXExecuted]="wasGetXExecuted"></child-component>
```